# Using the IBM Watson Concept Insights service for Natural Language Search

Tags: ibm-watson

We are trying to implement a natural language search function using the IBM Watson Cognitive Insights (CI) service. We want the user to be able to type in a question using natural language and then return the appropriate document(s) from a CI corpus. We are using CI rather than the Watson QA service to avoid the need for training and to keep Watson infrastructure costs down (i.e. avoid the need for a dedicated instance of Watson for each corpus/use case).

We are able to build the necessary corpus through the CI API but we are not sure which APIs to use in what order to accomplish the most precise/accurate query possible.

Our initial thought was to:

1. Accept the user’s natural language question and Post that text string to the “Identifies concepts in a piece of text” API (listed 6th from the bottom in the CI API Reference document) to get a list of concepts related to the question.
2. Then do a GET using the “Performs a conceptual search within a corpus” API (listed 3rd from the bottom in the CI API Reference document) to get a list of related documents back from the corpus.

The first question - is this the right way to go about achieving our objective described in the first paragraph of this post? Should we be combining the CI APIs differently or using multiple Watson services together to achieve the objective?

If our initial approach is the right one, then we are finding that when we submit a simple question (e.g. “How can I repair MySQL database corruption”) to the “Identifies concepts in a piece of text” API we are not getting a comprehensive list of associated concepts back. For example:

```
curl -u userid:password -k -d "How can I repair MySQL database corruption" https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights-beta/api/v1/graph/wikipedia/en-20120601?func=annotateText
```

returns:

```
[{"concept":"/graph/wikipedia/en-20120601/MySQL","coords":[[17,22]],"weight":0.85504603}]
```

Yet clearly there are other concepts associated with the example question (repair, corruption, database, etc.).

In another example we just submitted the text “repair” to the “Identifies concepts in a piece of text” API:

```
curl -u userid:password -k -d "repair" https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/concept-insights-beta/api/v1/graph/wikipedia/en-20120601?func=annotateText
```

and it returned:

```
[{"concept":"/graph/wikipedia/en-20120601/Repair","coords":[[0,6]],"weight":0.65392953}]
```

It seems that we should have gotten back the “Repair” concept from the first example also. Why would the API return the “repair” concept when we submit "repair" but not when we submit the text “How can I repair MySQL database corruption” which also includes the word “repair.”

Please advise as to the best way to implement a natural language search function based on the Watson Concept Insights service (perhaps in combination with other services if appropriate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much for your question and my apologies for being so late in answering it.

> The first question - is this the right way to go about achieving our objective >described in the first paragraph of this post? Should we be combining the CI >APIs differently or using multiple Watson services together to achieve the objective?

Doing the steps above would be a natural way to accomplish what you want to do. Please note however that the "annotate text" API uses currently exactly the same technology that the system has for connecting documents in your corpus to concepts in the core knowledge graph and as such, it is more "paragraph" oriented rather than individual question oriented. To be more precise, the problem of extracting concepts in a smaller piece of text is generally more difficult than in a larger piece of text because in the latter there is more context that can be used to make the right choices. Given this observation, the annotate text API goes the more conservative route again given its paragraph focus.

Having said that, the /v2 API that we now have does improve the speed and quality of the concept extraction technology, so it is possible that you would be more successful in using it in order to extract topics from  natural language questions. Here's what I would do/watch out for:

1) Clearly display to the user what CI extracted from the natural language in the input. Our APIs give you a way to retrieve a little abstract per concept which can be used to explain to a user what a concept means - do use that.

2) Give the user the ability to eliminate a concept from the extracted concept list (strike it out)

3) Since the concepts in concept insights currently correspond roughly to the notion of "topics", there is no way to deduce more abstract intent (for example, if the key to the meaning of a question is on a verb or an adjective as opposed to a noun, concept insights would be a poor way to deduce it). Watson does have technology oriented towards question answering as you pointed out before (the natural language classifier being one component of that), so I would take a look at that.

> Yet clearly there are other concepts associated with the example question >(repair, corruption, database, etc.).

The answer for this and the rest of the posted question is in a sense above - our intention was to provide a technology first for "larger text" which as I explained is an easier task. Since this question was first posted and today, we did introduce new annotation technology (/v2) so I would encourage the reader to see whether it performs a little better.

For the longer term, we do have the intention to give the user a formal way to specify context for a general application so that the chances of extraction of relevant concepts increase. We also have a plan to have the user be able to specify custom concepts, as it has been observed in the past that some topics of interest to users are impossible to match in our current design because they are not in wikipedia.